# Convert stored proc to table to be able to use in select statement

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, ref-cursor

I have to use existing stored procedure which returns `REF CURSOR`. I need to insert that `resultset` into a temporary table.

Spec of procedure is:

```
TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE get(p_one NUMBER ,p_two OUT cur);
```

How can I insert the `resultset` of this procedure into a table.

Comment: Do you know the structure of the result set this cursor will return?  Or are you trying to handle a generic weakly typed ref cursor `OUT` parameter (in other words, the structure of the result may change)?  Have you already created the temporary table?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, I have already created temporary table. But please let me know if it is possible to handle a generic weakly typed cursor also. Thank you.

Comment: How would you put the data from a generic, weakly typed ref cursor into a strongly typed existing temporary table.  That generally wouldn't make sense so I'd vehemently suggest rethinking the approach.  If you know the structure of the cursor that is being returned and that matches the structure of the temporary table you've created, then it's not terribly hard technically though it's still a bit concerning architecturally.

Comment: To handle the case of a generic cursor I think you'd be best off looking at the DBMS_SQL package. It can be a bit difficult to use, compared to the use of REF CURSORs, but has the advantage of being more generic. [Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-read the title of your question. Do you actually need to be able to select from a procedure?

If so, this can be achieved by using pipelined functions.

The process for this is:

1. Create an object type to represent the record-type you require.
2. Create a nested table type of the object.
3. Create a pipelined function which returns the nest table.
4. You can then select from this function.

This example should get you on your way:

```
    create or replace type to_test as object (
        val1  varchar2(32),
        val2  varchar2(32)
    );

    create or replace type tt_test as table of to_test;

    create or replace function demo_pipe return tt_test pipelined       
    is
       v_test to_test;
    begin
       for rec in (select * from user_tables) loop

           v_test := to_test(rec.table_name, rec.tablespace_name);

           pipe row (v_test);

       end loop;   

    end;
    /
    select * from table(demo_pipe);
```